# What does "saw the horse flinch" mean?

Tags: idioms, american-english

One of my coworkers (from the American midwest) said, "Hold up a minute, I saw the horse flinch." We weren't talking about horses or anything nearly related, but he then proceeded to ask a question that might have been skeptical or expressing disagreement. So I suspect this is an idiom, but I've never heard of it, and Google fails me.

What does "I saw the horse flinch" mean?

Comment: Wow, that's a new one on me. And google shows no results other than veterinary content. I'm inclined to say your coworker was just using a spontaneous (and somewhat baroque) personal metaphor.

Comment: If I had to try to parse a meaning, it would be: Horses are known to be "skittish," easily startled or "spooked" by danger or sudden movement. A horse flinching could be taken as a warning sign to look closely for a source of concern like a rattlesnake or rockslide. A somewhat similar but *established* idiom is "a canary in a coalmine," to indicate an early warning of otherwise undetected danger.

Comment: @AndyBonner that's similar to the impression I got, but they were talking about a subject I didn't fully understand in the first place, so I'm not exactly trusting my impression. It's entirely possible he made it up, I wouldn't put it past him.

Comment: I don't know the expression, but if it were used in my conversation I would guess that "the horse" refers to me. The coworker thinks: "Hang on, your reaction wasn't quite as expected, so perhaps you know something I don't. Let's delve a little."

Comment: I'd guess @AndyBonner is on the right track here. The expression has no significant currency, but it's possible that *in context* the speaker expected it to be understood as a metaphoric alternative to *I see **a chink in** [the / your / his] **armour***. That's to say, the conversational context is ***adversarial***, and the intended meaning is something along the lines of *[My opponent] **has shown weakness** [which I intend to capitalise on]*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a usage that has little (or ***no***) currency. All we have is a single isolated example that the OP remembers encountering, but which isn't meaningfully available to us for further examination.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd assumed this was an idiom that might be more known in it's locality given my other coworkers from that region seemed not to react to the idiom, but if indeed it's a personal metaphor and not an idiom then yeah, only speculation is possible which doesn't make for the best question.

Comment: Why not ask your colleague what he meant?

Comment: In Britain we might very well say, if a very controversial or new action were suggested, particularly one that might upset very conservative-minded people, that it might not be wise because 'we don't want to [frighten the horses](https://www.timesunion.com/living/article/They-don-t-scare-horses-do-they-871294.php)'

Comment: @ESCE: I'd be *very* surprised if anyone could "authoritatively" show that the cited utterance has a meaning different to what we're guessing here, but because there's a *faint* chance of that, I didn't feel comfortable closevoting as "Primarily Opinion-Based". That's why I decided to cite my own custom reason above - but obviously you couldn't possibly know before asking whether it was an established idiom or not, so no criticism was intended. And you do have the benefit of our best guess anyway, which is probably all you'd get if the question had remained open to accept formal Answers.

Comment: @user66974 not really comfortable with that, he's a bit higher up and probably doesn't even know I exist. 
FumbleFingers - that's fair and fine - I was hoping it was just an obscure idiom, but close voting is doing it's job here. Thanks for all your ideas though!